# Relation between eigenvalues depending on where the projector appears on the diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix

$$\Delta + P(k)$$

where $\Delta$ is the 1D graph Laplacian

$$\Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2}  & -\frac{1}{2} &      0       &    \dots     &        &    \dots     &       0      &       0      \\
 -\frac{1}{2} &       1      & -\frac{1}{2} &    \ddots    &        &              &              &       0      \\
 0      & -\frac{1}{2} &      1       & -\frac{1}{2} &        &              &              &    \vdots    \\
 \vdots    &    \ddots    & -\frac{1}{2} &      1       & \ddots &              &              &              \\
 &              &              &    \ddots    & \ddots &              &    \ddots    &    \vdots    \\
 \vdots    &              &              &              &        &    \ddots    &    \ddots    &       0      \\
 0      &              &              &              & \ddots &    \ddots    &       1      & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0      &       0      &    \dots     &              & \dots  &      0       & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
 \end{pmatrix} $$

and $P(k)_{ij} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jk}$ where $\delta$ is the Kroenecker delta symbol (i.e. $P(k)$ is a diagonal projector with only one non-zero element).

How do I prove that the smallest minimum eigenvalue for $\Delta + P(k)$ occurs when $k=1$ or $k=n$ (this appears to be true numerically), and all other minimum eigenvalues are larger? Is there some recurrence relation I could use? I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of both $\Delta$ and $P(k)$ analytically.

Comment: I can think of the following relations for the characteristic polynomial: for $1<k<n$, $\det(\Delta+P(k)-\lambda)=\det(\Delta-\lambda) + \det(\Delta_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}-\lambda)$; for $k=1$ or $k=n$, $\det(\Delta+P(k)-\lambda)=\det(\Delta-\lambda) + \det(\Delta_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}-\lambda) + \tfrac12\det(\Delta_{(n-2)\times(n-2)}-\lambda) + \tfrac14\det(\Delta_{(n-3)\times(n-3)}-\lambda)+...$. Perhaps it could help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get anywhere with it!